# Is there any error trying to make a review slider and my console is telling me slide is not defined at HTMLDivElement

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a review slider and my console is telling me slide is not defined at HTMLDivElement.

I have the following code:

```js
next.addEventListener(“click”, function() {
  curSlide++;
  container.forEach(
    (slide, indx), function(){
      slide.style.transform = `translateX(100 * (indx - curSlide)%)`;
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: You probably meant to use an arrow function: `(slide, indx) => {` (instead of the whole line `(slide, indx), function(){`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach, the syntax of forEach can be the following (among other possibilities) :

```
next.addEventListener(“click”, function() {
    curSlide++;
    container.forEach(function(slide, indx){
        slide.style.transform = translateX(100 * (indx - curSlide)%);
    });
});
```